# Mobile enterprise webpage covered by white box

Tags: bug, status-planned, mobile-web, stack-overflow-enterprise

When I open Stack Overflow (homepage or any question) on mobile, the screen is covered by a plain white box. If I scroll down, I can see the rest of the page below the modal, but everything at the top of the page is covered and there's no way to dismiss the modal.

[image: Screenshot]

Details:

- This only happens on my enterprise account: https://dropbox.stackenterprise.co/ is the URL from the screenshot
- I'm on an iPhone 12 pro max running iOS 15.3.1
- It happens on both Chrome and Safari
- I have been working around the issue by tapping "Request Desktop Site" on Chrome, or tapping the "full site" link at the bottom of the page. This removes the box (but the layout isn't the best on mobile)
- I have tried logging out and refreshing
- Opening the "inbox", "achievements", and "review queues" at the top will show the relevant list on top of the white box, but dismissing the list doesn't remove the white box

Answer (score 4):

We are aware of this issue and it will be fixed in the upcoming Enterprise update.

---

Our mobile views were deprecated a while ago and the current release got an unexpected bug with the mobile view. The mobile view is entirely removed in the next release of Enterprise and you will only be able to use the responsive view, which will have the final updates for all pages. We recommend switching to the responsive view (via the "full site" link in your workaround) and using only that view.